# Retrieve Text From Span Using Scrapy

Tags: python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I am having trouble extracting the "ADD TO CART" text from this HTML code. I'm new to web scraping so I don't know how to approach this. I need your help.

```
<button data-t-events="A" data-t-e-var78="$ - Add To Cart" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-wide" data-reactid=".8.1.0">
    
    <span data-reactid=".8.1.0.0" class="">ADD TO CART </span><i class="fa fa-caret-right" data-reactid=".8.1.0.1"></i></button>
```

I have tried

```
products = response.css('.btn-wide::text').extract_first()
print(products)
```

and

```
 products = response.css('.btn-wide span::text').extract_first()
 print(products)
```

Comment: You might be getting the `print` response empty because in your code I can see `data-reactid=".8.1.0.0"`. Which means that the website is using Reactjs. In order to extract data, you first need to render it so that scrapy can see the `button` and `span` tags.
Try using headers from that website, and you'll be able to extract the `Add to Cart` with the above codes you've already tried. If not, provide the website's link, and I'll help you.

Comment: awesome, the website page is https://www.newegg.com/evga-geforce-rtx-2080-super-08g-p4-3289-kr/p/N82E16814487469

Comment: I tried using this website https://curl.trillworks.com/ to get headers in the network tab but i don't think I'm copying the right network file headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a way using XPath and `data_reactid` is:

```py
response.xpath('//span[@data-reactid=".8.1.0.0"]/text()').get()
```

Comment: I tried using this command but when printing the variable I get back a blank list or the word NONE

Comment: Probably it happens because this part of html generates by JavaScript, if you add the URL, I will take a look at that.

Comment: https://www.newegg.com/evga-geforce-rtx-2080-super-08g-p4-3289-kr/p/N82E16814487469

Comment: `response.xpath("//*[@class='btn btn-primary btn-wide']//text()").get()`

Answer (score 0):

I see you tagged your question with `beautifulsoup` so here is one possible solution with this library:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


txt = '''<button data-t-events="A" data-t-e-var78="$ - Add To Cart" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-wide" data-reactid=".8.1.0">
    
    <span data-reactid=".8.1.0.0" class="">ADD TO CART </span><i class="fa fa-caret-right" data-reactid=".8.1.0.1"></i></button>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

text = soup.select_one('.btn-wide span').get_text(strip=True)
print(text)
```

Prints:

```
ADD TO CART
```